# Hidden hits in fight and control

Tags: technique

I know that police, security guards and other special forces learn how to fight and control people so that if they are videoed it would not look brutal. Where can I find these types of hits and control methods?

Comment: Watch US news, I think you will not conclude that the police know how to avoid looking brutal.

Comment: Do you have any evidence to back your assertion that *"if they are videoed it would not look brutal"*? A lot of control techniques are subtle or don't involve a massive range of movement so they don't explicitly look brutal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence that it has anything to do with reality.  Move it to snopes.com

Comment: I feel like there's a decent question here about how to do techniques discreetly. Admittedly, my brain goes more to ninja than to security personnel...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a fallacy.  I am SORA trained, and my police friends concur from their own training, that as a profession we/they are not trained to fight and control so that a video tape would seem unlike IRL.  That would be anti-ethical, and anyone who sought such training in these professions should not be trusted.

I also agree that there is a good question here, but as worded, makes bad assumptions.

In the better spirit of your question, though, there is always pressure points - tuite.  These don't work unless you spend a great deal of time working with it and martial arts in general.  But pressure points do offer many subtle means of strike and control than what might be seen in person or on camera.